# Interviewing - Reason for job change when leaving current employer too early

Tags: software-industry, job-change, job-offer

I am from an Indian community that works in one of the metro city for a reputed US based MNC firm. I joined this company 4 months back and this is my second employer (so you can guess I am just starting my career).  I worked around 2 years for my first employer.

In the initial months I discovered major cons about this company which leads me to shift to another company.  Now I am getting calls for jobs and their first question is "**Why do you want to leave your current organisation so early ?**" I am confused with what reason to give?

Here are the reasons for which I truly want to shift to another company:

- My role is software developer in this company but my reporting manager has zero technical knowledge. So I couldn't get any technical help from my superiors
- My team architecture is Director (Technical) -> Project Manager (Non T) -> Chief Manager (Non T & My Boss ) -> Software Developer (Me)
- I always have to contact BIG BOSS(Director) for any technical issue help!
- As a non-techie boss he/she commits any delivery date to the client which puts a huge burden on me
- I can not directly contact/coordinate/take inputs from client.  I address to my manager then he/she will take it further.
- No growth at all. No learning opportunity.
- Work on weekends but no Compensatory Off. No reimbursement.

So, out of the above which reasons should I tell when asked for it?

**Regarding Salary :**

As stated earlier this is my second company, I got 2X increment when I joined here. Now when I am looking for another one, I am expecting a 20% increase over it but its just 4 months. So is it valid?

Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks.

Comment: I guess it is not duplicate. I haven't got any offer rather it is a interview question.

Comment: Once you are not a trainee, you shouldn't expect technical help from your bosses. The meat of their job is not to provide technical help but to manage the clients and projects and personnel issues, etc.  And if they have technical knowledge it gets outdated quickly. It sounds as if you have no idea how to manage upwards. You need to understand how to make your nontechnical boss see why he needs your input first before agreeing to a deadline. This is an opportunity to learn how to manage in the workplace, running away from it is the worst mistake you can make at this point in your career.

Comment: @HLGEM it is not about running away.you will require some sort of technical help whether your trainee or experienced one ! What if i told u my boss goes away with my credits (in this case its money). and even if i performed better he always tells -ve to upper level.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773

Comment: That's pretty normal too especially for people who don't know how to play the political game (no one does it to me anymore.). Your problem is you need to learn how to play office politics. You are running away whether you think so or not. The most critical thing for you to learn in your career is how to manage problems and how to have an impact on solving problems. All workplaces have problems. All workplaces have things you won't like. Stop running away and start being proactive and learn office politics if you want to succeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are questioned on the motives always focus on the positives. It makes you come across better and leaves a better impression.

> No Growth at all. No learning opportunity.

This is what you should focus on. Talk about how moving forward, learning new things and challenging yourself is important to you. Your old role didn't have the learning opportunities and challenges you had hoped for so you need a role thats a better fit.

Comment: How can there be no learning opportunity if he is still needing to get technical advice from his boss?

Comment: Much of the learning process is having a skilled mentor and boss.

Comment: I personally have leared far more when I didn't have a skilled mentor or boss. That's when you have to step up your own game to succeed.

Answer (score 2):

I like Tom's answer.  Another one that is completely honest is "The expectations did not match the job description.  It wasn't a good fit."

Comment: Next question would come out then as "What were you expecting ?"

Comment: The job as described by the employer.  By expectations I would mean the expectations of the employer.

Answer (score -2):

Your list is fairly long. You could come up with "there was a long list of problems, like a, b, c and a few more" if asked, and say that while problems are acceptable and you can cope with them, all of these problems together were just too much to cope with, especially as your second post and with two years of experience; and that your manager was of no help, either (you did tell him about these problems and ask for assistance, didn't you?)

Comment: dont you think almost all points which i stated above would spread negativity to my future employer ?